# How to override configuration of a logrotate by another configuration

Tags: fedora, logrotate

There is a log folder on my disk, whose rotation policy is as follows

```
"/mnt/foo/shared/log/*.log" {
  # rotate the files daily
  daily
  # Save the last 7 days worth of logs before deleting
  rotate 7
  # missing file is not an error case - just ignore.
  missingok
  # this is important for the logs
  copytruncate
}
```

There is a set of logfiles in the `/mnt/foo/shared/log` folder named `indexer_cron_1.log`to `indexer_cron_4.log` I want only these 4 files to be rotated for 14 days. How do I override this configuration? I thought of creating another configuration but the thought of duplicate rotations occured and I stopped this. I do not have a machine where I can test this before, hence asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globbing to do this which means that you will have to explicitly specify which log files should be rotated for 14 days and which not:

```
/mnt/foo/shared/log/other_log_file_*_1.log
/mnt/foo/shared/log/other_log_file_*_2.log
/mnt/foo/shared/log/other_log_file_*_3.log
{
  # rotate the files daily
  daily
  # Save the last 7 days worth of logs before deleting
  rotate 7
  # missing file is not an error case - just ignore.
  missingok
  # this is important for the logs
  copytruncate
}
```

These log files rotate for 14 days:

```
/mnt/foo/shared/log/indexer_cron_[1234].log
{
  # rotate the files daily
  daily
  # Save the last 14 days worth of logs before deleting
  rotate 14
  # missing file is not an error case - just ignore.
  missingok
  # this is important for the logs
  copytruncate
}
```

There is no other simpler way how to include or exclude some log files from a rotation rule.